# Fastest way to read JSON data from MySQL

Tags: mysql, json, rust

Right now the way I read JSON data from MySQL is by fetching it as `String` and then parsing it into `JsonValue`, like this:

```
let q = "SELECT id, some_json_fld FROM some_table";
let rows: Vec<(i32, String)> = tx.query(q)?;
for r in rows {
    let v = serde_json::from_str(&r.1)?;
}
```

But since MySQL has a [native JSON data type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html), I was wondering, is there a faster way to do it?
At least in theory, there should be a faster way to convert the data from a MySQL binary JSON value to a Rust/Serde one.

(I am specifically asking for fetching JSON *objects*, not individual fields of JSON objects.)

*Note: This question should only be relevant for MySQL, but not for MariaDB, as the latter doesn't have a native JSON type and [uses LONGTEXT instead](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json-data-type/).*

Answer (score 0):

The [mysql](https://crates.io/crates/mysql) crate seems to provide a wrapper to easily serialize and deserialize JSON. With it, the process gets simplified to simply add a macro on top on your structs. Have you looked at it?

Comment: Well, yes, but that still uses string (de)serialization, doesn't it? 
My question wasn't about convenience but **speed**.

Answer (score 0):

If you often need some field(s) from a `JSON` string, pull it out *before* building the row.  And put it in a separate column.  And possibly index that column.

Use JSON only for stuff that rarely needs parsing.

Comment: I specifically said that I'm not talking about individual fields. In my case JSON *is* a suitable type, as the data can have varying fields with varying data types. Sometimes I only need to read a specific field (could be done like "some_json_fld->>'$.foo'" for example) and I know I can index it via _virtual generated column_ if needed. But other times I simply need to go over the whole documents and process them from my application.

Answer (score 0):

Your question, as I understand it, is "Can I use MySQL's optimized storage format to represent JsonValues rather than the JSON text format" and through that get faster serde performance?

The answer depends on another question: "Can I use the optimized storage format in JSON queries to MySQL instead of the standard text JSON format?".  If you cannot, then the answer to your question is very simple: no. If MySQL requires you to use the standard JSON format for communication then you have to use the standard JSON format.

If the answer is "Yes, MySQL lets you use its optimized storage format in queries", then the answer to your question is: maybe.  You can try writing your own serde functions that take `JsonValue` to the MySQL storage format and see if they're faster than using the serde for `JsonValue` to text JSON.  But testing performance of that new serde alone would not be sufficient, you'd also have to test if MySQL queries are faster when done with the storage format than when done with the standard JSON format.

I did a quick skim of the documents you leaked and, as far as I can tell, you have to use the standard text JSON format to communicate with MySQL.  Which would mean the answer to your question (as I understand it) is no.

Comment: I generally agree with your thoughts. In theory, I can think of two possible ways to avoid the overhead of text JSON representation. One is the DB to return the *raw* data in its own binary format. The other way is the DB to somehow convert the data (via function, I guess) to another well-known binary format like `MessagePack` for example. Both have the potential to be considerably faster than the text JSON representation, especially the first one.

Comment: Again, this question begins with finding out if MySQL will let you use their on-disk format.  There's no point in speculating about possible performance benefits if it does not.

Second, the next logical question is: if the speed of JSON encoding is a problem, then why use MySQL-JSON?